# Делаю django ЧПУ с помощью slug но выдает ошибку

Tags: html, python, django

Я хочу чтобы url выводилося названия статьи типо `programs/kak-vzlomat-jopu`
 или как то так. И еще настораживает то что как рагумент берет `slug : 13` а это вообще из другой колонки в database

```
Traceback:

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  145.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  143.                 response = response.render()

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in render
  106.             self.content = self.rendered_content

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\response.py" in rendered_content
  83.         content = template.render(context, self._request)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py" in render
  61.             return self.template.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  171.                     return self._render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  150.             return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in _render
  163.         return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py" in render
  62.                 result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render
  937.                 bit = node.render_annotated(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  209.                     nodelist.append(node.render_annotated(context))

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py" in render_annotated
  904.             return self.render(context)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py" in render
  443.             url = reverse(view_name, args=args, kwargs=kwargs, current_app=current_app)

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\base.py" in reverse
  90.     return iri_to_uri(resolver._reverse_with_prefix(view, prefix, *args, **kwargs))

File "D:\Users\MAestro\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py" in _reverse_with_prefix
  668.         raise NoReverseMatch(msg)

Exception Type: NoReverseMatch at /programms/
Exception Value: Reverse for 'article_detailProgramms' with keyword arguments '{'slug': '13'}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['programms/(?P<slugProg>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']
```

views.py

```
class ProgramsList(ListView):
    model = Programs
    template_name = 'programs/programms.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProgramsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        list_exam = Programs.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(list_exam, self.paginate_by)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            file_exams = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            file_exams = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            file_exams = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['articles_top'] = Programs.objects.all().order_by('?')[:6]
        context['list_exams'] = file_exams
        return context



def ProgramsDetail(request, slugProg):

    Articles.objects.filter(slug=slugProg)
    programm_details = Articles.objects.filter(slug=slugProg).first()
    top_art = Articles.objects.all().order_by('-view')[:10]
    top_prog = Programs.objects.all().order_by('?')[:10]

    return render(
        request,
        'programs/programm.html',
        {
           'programm_details': programm_details,
            'top_art':top_art,
            'top_prog':top_prog,
        }
    )
```

urls.py

```
    urlpatterns=[
        path('', ProgramsList.as_view(), name='articles_listProgramms'),
        path('<slug:slugProg>/', views.ProgramsDetail, name='article_detailProgramms'),
        path('searchProgramm/', views.post_search, name='post_searchProgramm'),

    ]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

class Programs(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200, verbose_name='Название Программы')
    storyPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Расширенное описание, функционал и т.д')
    previewPrograms = models.ImageField(upload_to='' , verbose_name='Каритинка 260х180')
    slugProg = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title')
    languegesPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='языки которые поддерживает программа')
    demandPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Требования')
    memoryPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Место, на жестком диске')
    uploadPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Сыллка с установкой')
    downlandCount = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)



    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Программы'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Программы'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

в шаблоне передаю slug в url вот так

```
  <a href="{% url 'article_detail'  slug=top.slugProg %}">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как пример мой вариант. Все лишнее удалено )

model.py (обрати внимание на `get_absolute_url`)

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120,
                             verbose_name='Title')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='URL')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/post/%s/" % (self.slug)
```

url.py (попробуй изменить адрес на /категория/slug были на этом как то проблемы)

```
path('post/<slug:slug>/', views.DetailPost.as_view(), name='detail'),
```

view.py попробуй через CBV.

```
class DetailPost(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'detail.html'
```

в admin.py строка `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}` позволяет сделать автозаполнение поля slug на основе title

Answer (score 0):

В `admin.py` в класс админа необходимо ввести строку `prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}`