# Django: Делаю URL ЧПУ и выводит ошибку

Tags: python, django

Я добавляю в модель поле slugField и после выполнения миграции у меня появляется ошибка. При том, что я уже использовал этот код и он полностью работал.

[image: текст ошибки]

models.py

```
class Programs(models.Model):
    titleProg = models.CharField(max_length=200 , verbose_name='titleProg')
    storyPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Расширенное описание, функционал и т.д')
    previewPrograms = models.ImageField(upload_to='' , verbose_name='Каритинка 260х180')
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True, verbose_name='URL', default='')
    languegesPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='языки которые поддерживает программа')
    demandPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Требования')
    memoryPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Место, на жестком диске')
    uploadPrograms = models.TextField(default='' , verbose_name='Сыллка с установкой')
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)




    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Программы'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Программы'




    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titleProg

    def __str__(self):
        return self.titleProg

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return "/programms/%s/" % (self.slug)
```

views.py

```
class ProgramsList(ListView):
    model = Programs
    template_name = 'programs/programms.html'
    paginate_by = 6

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProgramsList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        list_exam = Programs.objects.all()
        paginator = Paginator(list_exam, self.paginate_by)

        page = self.request.GET.get('page')

        try:
            file_exams = paginator.page(page)
        except PageNotAnInteger:
            file_exams = paginator.page(1)
        except EmptyPage:
            file_exams = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)
        context['articles_top'] = Programs.objects.all().order_by('?')[:6]
        context['list_exams'] = file_exams
        return context

class ProgramsDetail(DetailView):
    model = Articles
    template_name = 'programs/programm.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProgramsDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['top_art'] = Articles.objects.all().order_by('-view')[:10]
        context['top_prog'] = Programs.objects.all().order_by('?')[:10]
```

urls.py

```
path('', ProgramsList.as_view(), name='articles_listProgramms'),
path('programms/<slug:slug>/', views.ProgramsDetail, name='article_detailProgramms'),
path('searchProgramm/', views.post_search, name='post_searchProgramm'),
```

Comment: У Вас уже есть заполненные строки в созданной ранее БД?

Comment: Да есть , а нужно очисть

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Делаю django ЧПУ с помощью slug но выдает ошибку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1010075/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%8e-django-%d0%a7%d0%9f%d0%a3-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-slug-%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83)

Comment: @ZaArs не дубликат, там ошибки другие.

Comment: @LehaJublin Если это был вопрос, то да, следует очистить базу полностью. Обычно это решает проблему. Если поможет – отпишите, представлю как решение.

Comment: Оу да спасибо проблема решилося , я отчистил базу

Comment: @LehaJublin Добавил ответ, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как решение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для решения Вашей проблемы необходимо очистить БД, если в ней уже есть записи, и только после этого выполнить миграцию.

Проблема заключается в том, что, при добавлении нового поля в модель, Django не знает, чем заполнить это поле в тех записях, которые уже были сделаны. По умолчанию он оставляет там `null`, однако это противоречит установленному Вами ограничению `unique`, в связи с чем и возникает ошибка.